# Subjunctive for "Il est recommandé/suggéré que"

Tags: subjonctif

Normally a subjunctive is required for "I recommend/suggest that ..."

> Je recommande/suggère que tu **fasses** de l'exercice tous les jours.

What about for "It is recommended/suggested that ..."? It is a recommendation/suggestion, but it is made in general and not by any particular person, so I'm not sure whether a subjunctive is needed.

> Il est recommandé/suggéré que tu (fais/fasses) de l'exercice tous les jours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a conjugated verb after *recommander* and *suggérer* the use of the subjunctive is required because we are not sure the future action will happen.
If you want to make a statement that does not address a particular person and is taken as some sort of general advice then you should use an infinitive and not a conjugated verb :

> Il est recommandé de faire de l'exercice tous les jours.